# Interceptor can't access Action Parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, interceptor, valuestack

I'm creating an example for struts2 interceptors. I created a simple login page and used a custom interceptor class to encrypt the input. But the interceptor is reading the values of input from `ValueStack` as `null`.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I suppose `struts.xml` and interceptor class are enough data for this. If you need some more of my code, please tell.

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="myPackage" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="encrypt" class="com.keyur.struts2.interceptors.EncryptDecryptInterceptor"/>
        </interceptors>
        <action name="validatorAction" class="com.keyur.struts2.ActionClasses.validatorClass" method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="encrypt"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**Interceptor .java File**

```
package com.keyur.struts2.interceptors;

import com.keyur.struts2.ActionClasses.validatorClass;
import com.keyur.struts2.beans.EncryptorDecryptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack;

public class EncryptDecryptInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        EncryptorDecryptor encdec = new EncryptorDecryptor();

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String result = arg0.invoke();

        ValueStack stack = arg0.getStack();
        String username = stack.findString("username");
        String password = stack.findString("password");

        System.out.println("Username: "+((validatorClass)stack.peek()).getUsername());
        System.out.println("Password: "+((validatorClass)stack.peek()).getPassword());
        //System.out.println(username);
        //System.out.println(password);

        //stack.set("username", encdec.encryptText(username));
        //stack.set("password", encdec.encryptText(password));

        return result;
    }
}
```

`EncryptorDecryptor` is the a separate class which I have defined and it is working correctly on it's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access parameters, the `params` interceptor should go first

```
<action name="validatorAction" class="com.keyur.struts2.ActionClasses.validatorClass" method="execute">
   <interceptor-ref name="params"></interceptor-ref>
   <interceptor-ref name="encrypt"></interceptor-ref>
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
   <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Your problem is that those parameters don't go to the `valueStack`, and you should probably get them from the action context.

```
Map params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

But after `params` interceptor they should be there.

Comment: Ooh yes, I see.
So when I define my own interceptor reference, the default interceptor reference doesn't take effect. Right?

Comment: Correct, you were defining an interceptor stack with only your interceptor. You must define the full stack of interceptors to use.