# User data carriage using Interceptors in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 framework to implement the MVC architecture in my Web application. While allowing the user to obtain an ID-specific session, I need to take the **username and password from a JSP form**. Instead of passing this data to the Action class directly, I want to check the validity of the values in an Interceptor and then check or continue the flow depending on business logic-specific criteria.

Hence, my quest is to obtain the **user data from the JSP form in the Interceptor**. What is (if there's any) way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interceptor can't access Action Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650146/interceptor-cant-access-action-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

If you are validating the username and password through a  call to a DB or another service,it would be better to have a separate action for it.
However subsequent calls to business logic can be prehandled via the request context in the interceptor itself.